# Format fullcalendar date for asp.net mvc url routing

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, date, fullcalendar

I'm trying to format the 'date' parameter in the fullCalendar dayClick so it's passed to a url which can be interpreted by my routing to redirect to the correct controller. Here is my js;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        theme: true,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: ''

        },

        defaultView: 'month',
        editable: false,
        allDay: true,
        dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {



            if (allDay) {

                **window.location.href = "Browse/" + date.format('dd-mm-yyyy';**

            }

        },
        events: function (start, end, callback) {
            // do some asynchronous ajax
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            $.getJSON("/WhatsOn/CalendarData/",

                function (result) {
                    if (result != null) {
                        for (i in result) {
                            var calEvent = result[i];



                            calEvent.start = new Date(parseInt(calEvent.start.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", ""), 10));
                            calEvent.end = new Date(parseInt(calEvent.end.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", ""), 10));

                            calEvent.url = "Details/" + calEvent.ID;
                        }
                    }

                    var calevents = result;
                    // then, pass the CalEvent array to the callback
                    callback(calevents);


                });


        }

    });
});


</script>
```

Obviuosly this isn't working, the date being returned is in the format

```
Browse/Mon Aug 01 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
```

I've looked in the fullcalendar.js and I can't find where this date is fomated.
Any help would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
window.location.href = 'Browse/' + 
    date.getDate() + '-' + 
    (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + // months are zero based
    date.getFullYear();
```